# How to associate foreignkey data in django 3.0

Tags: django

How do I pull all of the users and put their full name into a context that I pass to a view?  My view currently pulls all of the filtered rows and I want to replace the id of the user with their full name before I pass the context to the view.  This is probably very simple, but I can't seem to make it work.  The field trigger_caused_by holds the id of the user that made the change that fired the trigger.

Account models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="Email Account")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="First Name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Last Name")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is Account Active")
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is Account Approved")
    readonly = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Read Only Account")
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Staff Account")
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Admin Account")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email} - {self.last_name}, {self.first_name}"

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.last_name and self.first_name:
            full_name = self.last_name + ", " + self.first_name
            return full_name
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_approved(self):
        return self.approved

    @property
    def is_readonly(self):
        return self.readonly

    @property
    def user_id(self):
        return self.id
```

Historical models.py

```
class TCVBaseHistorical(models.Model):
    opportunity_id = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, verbose_name='Connected Oppporunity ID')
    trigger_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name='Trigger Type')
    new_trigger_value = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='New Trigger Value')
    datetime_of_trigger = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True,
                                               verbose_name='Date/Time of Trigger')
    new_date_value = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='New Date Value')
    date_field_changed = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Date Field Changed")
    money_field_changed = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Money Field Changed")
    estimated = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.0,
                                         verbose_name='Estimated')
    estimated_base = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.0,
                                         verbose_name='Estimated Base')
    trigger_caused_by = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Trigger Caused By')
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=True)

#    def __str__(self):
#        if self.trigger_type == 'tier':
#            return f'{self.trigger_type} - '{self.opportunity_id} - {self.trigger_caused_by} - {self.active}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Historical'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Historicals'

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Historical views.py

```
class HistoricalRoleList(ListView):
    model = TCVBaseHistorical
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "Opportunity/Historical/HistRole.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        list_historicals = super(HistoricalRoleList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        usersinfo = User.objects.all()
        for _ in list_historicals:
            caused_by = getattr(list_historicals, 'trigger_caused_by')
            for _ in usersinfo:
                user = getattr(usersinfo, str(User.user_id))
                if caused_by == user:
                    list_historicals.full_name = user.get_full_name()
        return list_historicals

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        cur_opp = Current_Opportunity.objects.get().current_opportunity
        return qs.filter(trigger_type='role', opportunity_id=cur_opp).order_by('-datetime_of_trigger')
```

Comment: Unless you are an expert, I suggest you avoid AbstractBaseUser. As explained here, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: The user field isn't the issue.  I've used this extension of the AbstractBaseUser for a while now and haven't had any issues with it.  The thing I'm having an issue with is comparing two fields in an object and seeing if they are equal.  I have tried overriding the __eq__ and can't make that work either.